# How to populate my tableView in Swift 2 from array of dictionaries?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary, menu

Hi I'm a swift newbie.

I need to populate my app's menu dinamically in a tableview but I'm having trouble appending an array of dictionaries in an associative array.

I have this class for the menu items.

```
class Menu: NSObject {

    // properties
    var id:String = ""
    var name:String = ""

}
```

I have this json format from an api ,

```
[{
    "id": "local",
    "name": "Local"
}, {
    "id": "sports",
    "name": "Sports"
}, {
    "id": "bajacalifornia",
    "name": "Baja California"
},...
]
```

So in my MenuModel I get the items with json and append to array of objects and notify with a delegate when the data is ready in my menu controller

```
if let items = json["items"].array {

    for menuitem in items {

   // Create menu objects off of the JSON response
   let menuObj = Menu()

   menuObj.id = menuitem["id"].stringValue
   menuObj.name = menuitem["name"].stringValue

   arrayItems.append(menuObj)
   }

   self.menuArray = arrayItems

  // Notify the delegate that the data is ready
  if self.delegate != nil {
      self.delegate!.menuReady()
  }
} // end let items
```

I need this data structure in the Menu Controller. So my my problem is that I can't assign the array of objects into Array's key "News" to populate my tableview and show the options in the menu.

I need append self.menuArray into "News" item's array.

```
// data structure  to fill the menu tableview
let menuSectionHeaders = ["News", "Contact", Media]
var items = [
    "News": [["id":"local","name":"Local"],["id":"sports","name":"Sports"],["id":"bajacalifornia","name":"Baja California"],...more options],
    "Contact": ["comments"],
    "Media": ["Photos","Videos"]
]
```

My menu's controller code right now works but with  static data in this methods, and works fine but I need to fill the tableview dynamically with that data structure I showed above and I can't.

```
//Static Data and working code.

let menuSectionHeaders = ["News", "Contact","Media"]
var staticItems = [
    "News" : ["local", "sports", "bajacalifornia"],
    "Contact" : ["comments"],
    "Media" : ["Photos","Videos"]
]


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return menuSectionHeaders.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return menuSectionHeaders[section].uppercaseString
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let key = sectionHeaderName(forSection: section)
    return staticItems[key]!.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell?
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newscell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    }if indexPath.section == 1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("contactcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    }
    else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mediacell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    }
    let key = sectionHeaderName(forSection: indexPath.section)
    cell!.textLabel?.text = staticItems[key]![indexPath.row].capitalizedString
    return cell!
}


func sectionHeaderName(forSection section: Int) -> String {
    return menuSectionHeaders[section]
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the problem? Are you having trouble with looping through to get values or is it a typecasting issue?

Comment: Hi @GJZ, I need to append my array of objects into the News key.

Comment: **News, Media and Contact** are my title Sections, the problem is the "News" content is and array of objects (from json), and the content of others are an simple array.                                                                                        I I have this ` ["id":"local","name":"Local"],["id":"sports","name":"Sports"],["id":"bajacalifornia","name":"Baja California"]` and want to put here var `items = [
    "News": [**HERE**],
    "Contact": ["comments"],
    "Media": ["Photos","Videos"]
]`